# Application Gateway deployment failed due to resource provision operation did not complete within the allowed timeout period

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-application-gateway

**Summary**

- Application Gateway deployment in `ApplicationGatewaySubnet` was failed
- I deleted the failed gateway but related `appgwILB` & `appgwLoadBalancer` remained (bug? should be deleted when I deleted failed gateway resource)
- Neither can re-create application gateway in `ApplicationGatewaySubnet`, nor can delete `ApplicationGatewaySubnet` because of remaining `appgwILB` & `appgwLoadBalancer`
- Again `appgwILB` & `appgwLoadBalancer` should have been deleted when I deleted failed Application Gateway resource, but those two remained & causing problem

**Details**
Tried to create application gateway (WAF v2) using Azure portal. But after 2 hours, the deployment failed with following error:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource provision operation did not complete within the allowed timeout period."
    }
}
```

Since it failed, I deleted the application gateway thinking that I will try to re-create it. But now cannot deploy application gateway to the same subnet `ApplicationGatewaySubnet`:

[image: Cannot deploy application gateway to existing subnet]

I tried to delete the `ApplicationGatewaySubnet` but could not:

[image: Cannot delete application gateway subnet]

I realized that even though application gateway is deleted, the internal load balancer remained:

[image: internal load balancer remained]

Tried to delete Public IP address, but cannot delete because it is associated to `appgwLoadBalancer` even though application is deleted:

[image: Cannot delete public IP because it is associated to appgwLoadBalancer]

**How to resolve this?**
I want to use `ApplicationGatewaySubnet` and Public IP (that was used previously) and re-create application gateway.

Comment: hello @hassan , it seems that the subnet and IP are used by other load balancer , for subnet its being used by `appgwILB` and the IP is being used by `appgwLoadBalancer`.. You will have to delete them as well. if you don't want to delete , then please use new set of resources to be used by the app gateway

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Do you understand that `appgwILB ` & `appgwLoadBalancer` are auto-created and should also be deleted when I deleted the failed gateway? I added summary at top, please read the question again!

Comment: can you please provide a reference document which you are using to create application gateway ? i will try to test using that in my environment

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Got reply from Azure support that there was an incident in Azure datacenter during the time I tried to create Application Gateway, maybe that's why deployment failed. But problem is those 2 remaining load balancers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `appgwILB` & `appgwLoadBalancer` were deleted automatically after a few days (mentioned that we got a reply from Azure support "there was an incident in the Azure datacenter during the time we tried to create Application Gateway"). Therefore was able to use the same public IP and deployed application gateway in the same `ApplicationGatewaySubnet`.